# Spring MVC AngularJS separate front-end with back-end

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a pretty big Spring MVC + AngularJS app. Spring MVC mostly work as the REST API, but not completely (security, some routing, Wro4j resources packing)
at the time i started it's development, wasn't experienced much in Web Projects.

App is deployed on Amazon Elasticbeanstalk.

The Front-end guy joins me and we have to separate the dev process somehow.

**The Qeustions are:**

1. What is the basic steps i have do to separate them into the 2 apps?
2. What is the deployment process? are the front-end/back-end must be deployed as separate apps?
3. Any advises on best practices in general ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only reason to separate angularJS app and deploy separately if your application is very large and backend build takes a lot of time(10+ mins), or you do not want to rebuild entire application every time for any good reason. Putting angularJS application under spring MVC even if it's only main page gives you a lot of advantages: you can use spring ecosystem, centralized security, login and access control, SSO, lot of integrations, spring social etc..
Not sure why you really need to separate them into 2 apps. But anyway.

1. If you want to separate angularJS app you need to move any logic about routing from controllers or jsp files to angularjs app. Implement token base auth/login. Then you can define **REST_BASE_URL** constant in constant block of angular and use everywhere($http, $resource) to generate request url. If you work basically on angular part you can setup backend on remote server and run only angular application locally using nginx or any tiny server, and work on Google Chrome(make sure you run chrome using this agruments: **--args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir ~/**). Unfortunately you can't disable CSRF check in Firefox.
2. You can build and deploy 2 apps separately which is nice.
3. You also need to create your own **AuthenticationEntryPoint** and return **SC_UNAUTHORIZED**(401) instead of login page in spring rest. If angular side you can add global interceptor to catch 401 and show login page or dialog like this:

```js
.factory('authHttpResponseInterceptor',['$q','$location',function($q,$location){
        return {
            response: function(response){
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    console.log("Response 401");
                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy frontend project on node or lite server or apache, get/post data from tomcat which run the Spring MVC, you may have cross-domain problems, You can use

`<mvc:cors>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
    </mvc:cors>`

to solve the cross-domain problems.

Comment: also not a complete answer.

Answer (score -2):

The "MVC" is Spring MVC stands for Model View Controller. The "view" could be html or jsp (you would specify the view details in your servlet). You would not need to deploy them separately. How are you building your project? Maven is a good idea. It will wrap all your front-end and back-end code into a war/jar file and then you'd jus have to deploy it on a server.

Your AngularJS code would be incorporated in your spring "views" and the JS part of it would sit in your app.js. So there is no need to keep them separate. Your front-end guy could write the front-end code and you'd just have to integrate it into your project before building and deploying.

However, if you absolutely must separate them, there's only one option I can think of. Place all your UI code(HTML, CSS, JS) in a folder(let's call it '**project**') in the "webapp" folder in Tomcat along with the war file(let's call it **project-war.war**). When deployed, you just have to ensure that your URLs are correctly mapped. For example, if app.js(residing in project/js/app.js) wants to call the Java service for `/controller/action`, the URL must be `../../../project-war/controller/action`.

Comment: sorry, but my question was about the separation. I know, what it will be better to separate on this stage. further - more mess. Your answer is not answering the question at all.

Comment: Seriously, you're just talking about making Spring + AngularJS app. And this is not the question. You can just remove your answer then.

Comment: Wow, @user1935987.  So much for trying to help. I'll still leave my answer there.

Comment: Thank you for help, but your answer is really not relevant.